# Joomla 2.5 creating component and saving data

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, admin

I have been using this documentation (the only one I can find on the web) to build a component:
http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Introduction

I can understand it to a certain extent, however it does really lack any definition. The component I have created works to a degree, though I am having some wier problems.

Basically all I need the component to do is simply load a settings area to set a few values, and through it be able to change those values. Here is a breakdown of what I have:

A view for a form, loading in form data from database.
toolbars setup for save/apply and cancel.

This loads with no errors, and according to all docs on joomla I have found, by initializing a  JControllerForm instance with a JTable connected in the model, simple saving of forms should work automatically. However even though there is absolutely no reference anywhere in the code to a view with an s at the end (main view is tireapi, the forms always redirects to tireapis).

This brings up a 500 error, as there is no place set that has that view. The documentation does include a list for a view, however I have only one row I need to edit, so a list is pointless. I know parameters can be set to components rather then making a database field, however I am unable to find any documentation relating to it.

What I am looking for is direction on how to stop the component from redirecting to a none existent view, and properly save the data. Links to documentation that not only shows example code, but describes functions and how they work would be beneficial.

Here is some of the code, feel free to point out anything I might be completely overlooking (I am newer to creating components):

tireapi.php:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

// Get an instance of the controller prefixed by TireAPI
$controller = JController::getInstance('TireAPI');

// Get the task
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$task = $jinput->get('task', "", 'STR' );

// Perform the Request task
$controller->execute($task);

// Redirect if set by the controller
$controller->redirect();
?>
```

controller.php:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

class TireAPIController extends JController{
    function display($cachable = false){
        // set default view if not set
        $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $input->set('view', $input->getCmd('view', 'TireAPI'));

        // call parent behavior
        parent::display($cachable);
    }
}
?>
```

controllers/tireapi.php:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
 defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
// import Joomla controllerform library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controllerform');
class TireAPIControllerTireAPI extends JControllerForm{}
?>
```

models/tireapi.php:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
// import the Joomla modellist library
jimport('joomla.application.component.modeladmin');
class TireAPIModelTireAPI extends JModelAdmin{
    protected $settings; //define settings

    public function getTable($type = 'TireAPI', $prefix = 'TireAPITable', $config = array()){
        return JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
    }

    public function getSettings(){ //grab settings from database
        if(!isset($this->settings)){
            $table = $this->getTable();
            $table->load(1);
            $this->settings = $table;
        }
        return $this->settings;
    }
    public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true){
    // Get the form.
        $form = $this->loadForm('com_tireapi.tireapi', 'tireapi',
            array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));
        if (empty($form)){
            return false;
        }
        return $form;
    }
    protected function loadFormData(){
        // Check the session for previously entered form data.
        $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_tireapi.edit.tireapi.data', array());
        if (empty($data)){
            $data = $this->getSettings();
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
?>
```

tables/tireapi.php:

```
<?php
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla table library
jimport('joomla.database.table');
class TireAPITableTireAPI extends JTable
{
    function __construct( &$db ) {
        parent::__construct('#__tireapi', 'id', $db);
    }
}
?>
```

views/tireapi/view.html.php:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla view library
jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

class TireAPIViewTireAPI extends JView{
        function display($tpl = null){

            $form = $this->get('Form');
            $item = $this->get('Settings');

            // Check for errors.
            if(count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))){
                JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
                return false;
            }
            // Assign data to the view
            $this->item = $item;
            $this->form = $form;

            $this->addToolBar();

            // Display the template
            parent::display($tpl);
        }
        protected function addToolBar() {
            $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
            JToolBarHelper::title(JText::_('COM_TIREAPI_MANAGER_TIREAPIS'));
            JToolBarHelper::apply('tireapi.apply');
            JToolBarHelper::save('tireapi.save');
            JToolBarHelper::cancel('tireapi.cancel');
        }
}
?>
```

views/tireapi/tmpl/default.php:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access');

// load tooltip behavior
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
?>
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_tireapi&layout=edit&id='.(int) $this->item->id); ?>"
      method="post" name="adminForm" id="tireapi-form">
    <fieldset class="adminform">
            <legend><?php echo JText::_( 'COM_TIREAPI_DETAILS' ); ?></legend>
            <ul class="adminformlist">
    <?php foreach($this->form->getFieldset() as $field): ?>
                    <li><?php echo $field->label;echo $field->input;?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="tireapi.edit" />
        <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

These are all the files I can think of that may matter, let me know if I should include anymore.

UPDATE:
Now I can get the redirect problem to stop, however it will not save data.
I get this error:
You are not permitted to use that link to directly access that page (#1).

This is the last hurdle to get this extremely basic admin feature to work. Any ideas?
To clarify, I set the forms though an xml file and that loads properly, even filling them with the proper data from database. However when I click "apply" it just directs me back to the form with the error listed above, without saving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main question that you left open is where do you want it to redirect? Joomla by default redirects to the list view (by adding an 's' to the view name unless you specify a list view directly).

You can override this in a couple of ways:

In your controller (controllers/tireapi.php), set your own list view. I think you can even make this the same view:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->view_list = 'tireapi';
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Override the save function to change the redirect that happens after save (again in the controller). This works by changing the redirect that happens naturally to something else:

```
public function save($key = null, $urlVar = null) {
    $return = parent::save($key, $urlVar);
    $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_tireapi&view=tireapi'));
    return $return;
}
```

One of those should do the trick for you.

** UPDATE

To get the item to checkout initially you will want to change how your component handles no view being set. Right now you just set the view, instead, let's redirect! Updated controller.php is below.

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

class TireAPIController extends JController{
    function display($cachable = false){
        // set default view if not set
        $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $view = $input->get('view');
        if (!$view) {
            JFactory::getApplication()->redirect('index.php?option=com_tireapi&task=tireapi.edit&id=1');
            exit();
        }

        // call parent behavior
        parent::display($cachable);
    }
}
?>
```

NOTE: This will work really poorly if more than one person needs to edit this, since the system checks it out when you open the component if you also have it redirect back to this page after saving. Because then it will always be checked out to the last person that edited it so the next person won't be able to open it. If only one person edits it, it will be fine.

SECOND NOTE: If you don't want to hack the checkout system you can also ignore it during the save process, which is basically the same level of hacking.

Below is a copy of the save function from controllerform.php in `libraries/joomla/application/component/`. This is what is running on save normally (because of where you inherit from. I have removed the check if the item is checked out. So if you put this in your tireapi.php controller where the `parent::save...` bit is, it will run instead and you don't have to bother with checking the item out (i.e. ignore all the comments...). (Honestly, in your case, you can probably delete a lot more of this, but this is what is happening on save, btw!)

```
public function save($key = null, $urlVar = null)
{
    // Check for request forgeries.
    JSession::checkToken() or jexit(JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'));

    // Initialise variables.
    $app   = JFactory::getApplication();
    $lang  = JFactory::getLanguage();
    $model = $this->getModel();
    $table = $model->getTable();
    $data  = JRequest::getVar('jform', array(), 'post', 'array');
    $checkin = property_exists($table, 'checked_out');
    $context = "$this->option.edit.$this->context";
    $task = $this->getTask();

    // Determine the name of the primary key for the data.
    if (empty($key))
    {
        $key = $table->getKeyName();
    }

    // To avoid data collisions the urlVar may be different from the primary key.
    if (empty($urlVar))
    {
        $urlVar = $key;
    }

    $recordId = JRequest::getInt($urlVar);

    // Populate the row id from the session.
    $data[$key] = $recordId;

    // The save2copy task needs to be handled slightly differently.
    if ($task == 'save2copy')
    {
        // Check-in the original row.
        if ($checkin && $model->checkin($data[$key]) === false)
        {
            // Check-in failed. Go back to the item and display a notice.
            $this->setError(JText::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_CHECKIN_FAILED', $model->getError()));
            $this->setMessage($this->getError(), 'error');

            $this->setRedirect(
                JRoute::_(
                    'index.php?option=' . $this->option . '&view=' . $this->view_item
                    . $this->getRedirectToItemAppend($recordId, $urlVar), false
                )
            );

            return false;
        }

        // Reset the ID and then treat the request as for Apply.
        $data[$key] = 0;
        $task = 'apply';
    }

    // Access check.
    if (!$this->allowSave($data, $key))
    {
        $this->setError(JText::_('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_SAVE_NOT_PERMITTED'));
        $this->setMessage($this->getError(), 'error');

        $this->setRedirect(
            JRoute::_(
                'index.php?option=' . $this->option . '&view=' . $this->view_list
                . $this->getRedirectToListAppend(), false
            )
        );

        return false;
    }

    // Validate the posted data.
    // Sometimes the form needs some posted data, such as for plugins and modules.
    $form = $model->getForm($data, false);

    if (!$form)
    {
        $app->enqueueMessage($model->getError(), 'error');

        return false;
    }

    // Test whether the data is valid.
    $validData = $model->validate($form, $data);

    // Check for validation errors.
    if ($validData === false)
    {
        // Get the validation messages.
        $errors = $model->getErrors();

        // Push up to three validation messages out to the user.
        for ($i = 0, $n = count($errors); $i < $n && $i < 3; $i++)
        {
            if ($errors[$i] instanceof Exception)
            {
                $app->enqueueMessage($errors[$i]->getMessage(), 'warning');
            }
            else
            {
                $app->enqueueMessage($errors[$i], 'warning');
            }
        }

        // Save the data in the session.
        $app->setUserState($context . '.data', $data);

        // Redirect back to the edit screen.
        $this->setRedirect(
            JRoute::_(
                'index.php?option=' . $this->option . '&view=' . $this->view_item
                . $this->getRedirectToItemAppend($recordId, $urlVar), false
            )
        );

        return false;
    }

    // Attempt to save the data.
    if (!$model->save($validData))
    {
        // Save the data in the session.
        $app->setUserState($context . '.data', $validData);

        // Redirect back to the edit screen.
        $this->setError(JText::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_SAVE_FAILED', $model->getError()));
        $this->setMessage($this->getError(), 'error');

        $this->setRedirect(
            JRoute::_(
                'index.php?option=' . $this->option . '&view=' . $this->view_item
                . $this->getRedirectToItemAppend($recordId, $urlVar), false
            )
        );

        return false;
    }

    // Save succeeded, so check-in the record.
    if ($checkin && $model->checkin($validData[$key]) === false)
    {
        // Save the data in the session.
        $app->setUserState($context . '.data', $validData);

        // Check-in failed, so go back to the record and display a notice.
        $this->setError(JText::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_CHECKIN_FAILED', $model->getError()));
        $this->setMessage($this->getError(), 'error');

        $this->setRedirect(
            JRoute::_(
                'index.php?option=' . $this->option . '&view=' . $this->view_item
                . $this->getRedirectToItemAppend($recordId, $urlVar), false
            )
        );

        return false;
    }

    $this->setMessage(
        JText::_(
            ($lang->hasKey($this->text_prefix . ($recordId == 0 && $app->isSite() ? '_SUBMIT' : '') . '_SAVE_SUCCESS')
                ? $this->text_prefix
                : 'JLIB_APPLICATION') . ($recordId == 0 && $app->isSite() ? '_SUBMIT' : '') . '_SAVE_SUCCESS'
        )
    );

    // Redirect the user and adjust session state based on the chosen task.
    switch ($task)
    {
        case 'apply':
            // Set the record data in the session.
            $recordId = $model->getState($this->context . '.id');
            $this->holdEditId($context, $recordId);
            $app->setUserState($context . '.data', null);
            $model->checkout($recordId);

            // Redirect back to the edit screen.
            $this->setRedirect(
                JRoute::_(
                    'index.php?option=' . $this->option . '&view=' . $this->view_item
                    . $this->getRedirectToItemAppend($recordId, $urlVar), false
                )
            );
            break;

        case 'save2new':
            // Clear the record id and data from the session.
            $this->releaseEditId($context, $recordId);
            $app->setUserState($context . '.data', null);

            // Redirect back to the edit screen.
            $this->setRedirect(
                JRoute::_(
                    'index.php?option=' . $this->option . '&view=' . $this->view_item
                    . $this->getRedirectToItemAppend(null, $urlVar), false
                )
            );
            break;

        default:
            // Clear the record id and data from the session.
            $this->releaseEditId($context, $recordId);
            $app->setUserState($context . '.data', null);

            // Redirect to the list screen.
            $this->setRedirect(
                JRoute::_(
                    'index.php?option=' . $this->option . '&view=' . $this->view_list
                    . $this->getRedirectToListAppend(), false
                )
            );
            break;
    }

    // Invoke the postSave method to allow for the child class to access the model.
    $this->postSaveHook($model, $validData);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: It definitely helped the redirect, however I get this: You are not permitted to use that link to directly access that page (#1). when I try to save, because it Is one page I removed "save" in favor of "apply" as well.

Comment: When linking to the page try using the following link: index.php?option=com_tireapi&task=tireapi.edit. (This is true from menu items or wherever, usually done in the list view that you don't have.) This calls the edit function in your controller which should checkout the item for you before directing to the form. That checkout should make you able to edit it

Comment: I will look into that, however one foreseeable issue is how to change the link in the admin panel. This is loading in the components menu and I have never seen any way to change this link. I will continue to tweak though.

Comment: Looking deeper adding the &task does not check me in/out as far as i can see. Basically under my understanding is that after the first fail i make it redirect to &task=tireapi.edit and then from there it should be checked out, If I am understanding properly. However editing again and clicking save does the same thing again.

Comment: Sorry. You have to add '&id=1' to the url so that it knows to check out item 1! full url should be index.php?option=com_tireapi&task=tireapi.edit&id=1. And for the menu item we have to change what happens if no view is specified. I'll update the answer with an option.

Comment: Thank you, I will not be able to test till monday but I feel this explains it extremely well.

Comment: it worked! for the most part anyway, its just not "saving" but that is far less of a problem at this point. I will get the mysql stuff working then give you the answer once It works :).

Comment: UPDATE: The error is a little strange, it adds the id up in increments (if you are editing 1 it saves a new row as 2 then displays 1 again and continues infinitely without editing ID 1)

Comment: You probably aren't including the id in the form data. Check if you have an input anywhere in the form that has the name `jform[id]` and value 1. Without this, the save function defaults to creating a new row. If it isn't there, add `<input type="hidden" name="jform[id]" value="1" />` at the end of the form near the hidden `task` input.

Comment: Tried a few things now, doesn't seem to be taking it. added in the hidden form, tried to switch "task" from tireapi.edit to tireapi.apply. Also tried to force any reference to ID in the save function of the controller to force it to see ID 1. From what i can see it is model->save that actually takes the form data an saves it. Should I be overriding this as well?

Comment: You shouldn't have to override it. Right before the `$model->save` you should see the $data being passed. Dump that `$data` variable and see if it contains the id and the rest of the data.

Comment: that was it :) thought the data was some joomla class being passed but it was a simple array so easy to force a value. Thank you for your help, wish i had more rep to give you more credit.

Comment: Glad we got you there. I'm working on developer tools for Joomla so it is nice to see what trips up newer developers and what they are trying to build. You may also be interested in following the proposal for a dedicated stack site for joomla: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real answer but your question is also not a real question (I had to read it 3 times).

The thing with the plural "s" (for tireapis) is what Joomla! does automatically. You can override that.

I suggest that you take a look at the core components (like com_banners).

What you need to do is to avoid the redirect. You should have only the "Save" button, that should keep you on the same page. While "Save & Close" redirects you to the plural page.

Comment: I was mainly testing with apply, though I did remove the save and close now. But problem with "apply" is that it does not read the jTables data like i "think" it should (no documentation I have seen explains it). Also sorry for making the question seem complex, was at around 60 different variations of code and no success so I was slightly annoyed as I wrote it.

Comment: As said, look at the core components and figure out how they work. Using Save or Save & Close should have no importance, JTable will still be used.