# Save and back button redirect to wrong template

Tags: button, joomla, components, toolbar

I created my first Joomla 3.6.2 component and everything's working fine - until ONE thing.

I click on a link in an overview template and reac the edit view. Now, if I click on Back-Button or Save-Button, he redirects me to a templatename which name doesn't exists **anywhere** (searched the **whole** project folder).

When I click on them, it seems to be my browser redirects to the singular word of it.... the view name on editing is "ladies" and he uses "lady" after clicking....

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joomla by default switch between singular and plural names.

When you are in Edit View and click 'Save' or 'Cancel' button joomla tries to redirect you into List view, and automatic add 's' to your view name.

You can overwrite default 'Save' and 'Cancel' methods in your controller file.

```
public function save($key = null, $urlVar = null) {
    $return = parent::save($key, $urlVar);
    $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_helloword'));
    return $return;
}

public function cancel($key = null, $urlVar = null) {
    $return = parent::cancel($key, $urlVar);
    $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_helloword'));
    return $return;
}
```

Please take a look at this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16113039/5088581

Comment: I added the snippets into every file once I suggest has to do with it.... nothing happens (or errors of course)

My strongest idea is admin/views/helloworld/tmpl/view.html.php? Is this correct? I added it here above and one time under the toolbar call... nothing happend

Comment: try to create controller file in /admin/controllers/ for your view.
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_backend_actions
this code should be in controller class

Comment: I added your snippet into admin/controllers/edit.php and edited the toolbar methods in view.html.php on JToolBarHelper::save to "('edit.save'); - now it says: Call to undefined method JControllerAdmin::save() [...] \controllers\edit.php :/

Comment: What views you have ? what names have ? ladies and lady ?

Maybe my early state project will help you
https://github.com/plyntex/dwportfolio

Notice that default view is 'Items' (list of all items) 
DwPortfolio is Edit View (for single item) 
Please take a look at files
/admin/controllers/dwportfolio.php
/admin/views/dwportfolio/view.html.php

Comment: Thank you!? It was just a tiny thing that was wrong >_< saved my day! :)